# Read in file with complicated format and tidy it

Tags: r, file-io, dataframe

I would like to read a file with a complex format into a data frame or data table. I simplified the format to have the simplest example which can still convey all of the complexity of the real case.

```
TITLE = "SomeTitleHere"
VARIABLES = "n","q[m3/hr]","gf[-]","pe[bar]","eff[%]",
ZONE DATAPACKING=POINT T="Design GF= 0.000 Q= 818.96 rpm=4800.",I=  4
  0    818.96002      0.00000      13.00000    
     61.92762
  1    818.96002      0.00000      29.86776    
     61.92762
 ZONE DATAPACKING=POINT T="Offdesign GF= 0.000 Q= 200.00 rpm=4800.",I=  4
  0    200.00000      0.00000      13.00000    
      0.00000
  1    200.00000      0.00000      37.79360    
     27.12768
 ZONE DATAPACKING=POINT T="Offdesign GF=  0.000 Q=1200.00 rpm=4800.",I=  4
  0   1200.00000      0.00000      13.00000
      0.00000
  1   1200.00000      0.00000      17.17662
     28.08889
 ZONE DATAPACKING=POINT T="Offdesign GF=  0.100 Q= 200.00 rpm=4800.",I=  4
  0    200.00000      0.10000     13.00000
      0.00000
  1    188.40880      0.04463      30.91997
     22.54672
 ZONE DATAPACKING=POINT T="Offdesign GF= 0.100 Q=1200.00 rpm=4800.",I=  4
  0   1200.00000      0.10000    13.00000    
      0.00000
  1   1177.85608      0.08308     15.94177
     13.05620
```

Format explanation: the first line (`TITLE = "SomeTitleHere"`) is some kind of comment and can be skipped. The second line contains prefixes for some variable names and their measurement units. Since I know which are the names of the variables, this line can also be skipped. 
Then, there are 2*n+1 "data blocks". Each data block is 5 lines long: the first is a title line, which contains the values of four variables, `Point`, `GFin`, `Qin` and `rpm` (thus it must be parsed). For example, for the first block the title line is

```
ZONE DATAPACKING=POINT T="Design GF= 0.000 Q= 818.96 rpm=4800.",I=  4
```

which corresponds to

```
      Point GFin     Qin  rpm
     Design  0.0  818.96 4800
```

Then, I have 4 lines of numeric/integer data without strings. The 4 lines really correspond to 2 lines of actual data, because the even lines are actually the last value of the odd lines! They contain the values of the eight variables `q1`,     `q2`, `GF1`, `GF2`, `pe1`, `pe2`, `eff1` and `eff2`. In other words, the first data block (lines 5-7 in the sample file)

```
ZONE DATAPACKING=POINT T="Design GF= 0.000 Q= 818.96 rpm=4800.",I=  4
  0    818.96002      0.00000      13.00000    
     61.92762
  1    818.96002      0.00000      29.86776    
     61.92762
```

corresponds to the following entry in the dataframe

```
  Point GFin     Qin  rpm     q1     q2 GF1 GF2 pe1      pe2     eff1     eff2
 Design  0.0  818.96 4800 818.96 818.96   0   0  13 29.86776 61.92762 61.92762
```

Applying the same logic, the final data frame corresponding to the above input file should be

```
> df
      Point GFin     Qin  rpm      q1        q2 GF1     GF2 pe1      pe2     eff1     eff2
1    Design  0.0  818.96 4800  818.96  818.9600 0.0 0.00000  13 29.86776 61.92762 61.92762
2 OffDesign  0.0  200.00 4800  200.00  200.0000 0.0 0.00000  13 37.79360  0.00000 27.12768
3 OffDesign  0.0 1200.00 4800 1200.00 1200.0000 0.0 0.00000  13 17.17662  0.00000 28.08889
4 OffDesign  0.1  200.00 4800  200.00  188.4088 0.1 0.04463  13 30.91997  0.00000 22.54672
5 OffDesign  0.1 1200.00 4800 1200.00 1177.8561 0.1 0.08308  13 15.94177  0.00000 13.05620
```

How can I go from my input file to this data frame, minimizing the level of manual intervention?

PS of course the real file has thousands more data blocks and much more variables for each data block. This was just a simple example.

EDIT I read about `readLines`, as suggested by an user, and I got here (TestFile is the file I provided at the start of the question):

```
# read test file TestFile.dat

# clear the workspace
rm(list=ls())
gc()
graphics.off()

# read full file
directory = "../test/"
filename = "TestFile.dat"
fullpath = paste0(directory,filename)
s = readLines(fullpath) # looks like R can easily read in one sweep even my original file, which has more than 60000 lines. Great!!!

# remove TITLE line and VARIABLES line
s=s[-2:-1]

# how many data points?
nstages = 1
nlines = 2*(nstages+1)+1
npoints = length(s)/nlines

# parser function
parse_point <- function(x) {}

# lapply the parser function to s
data_list=lapply(s,parse_point)    

# merge the list of data frames data_list in a single data frame
data=do.call("rbind",data_list)
```

I think the `lapply`+`do.call` trick is neat, and saves me the slowness of `for`. The problem is that don't know how to write a parser function which `lapply` can handle! Basically, `lapply` applies `parse_point` to one element of `s` at a time. This won't do: I need to parse 5 elements of `s` at a time, i.e., a data block:

```
ZONE DATAPACKING=POINT T="Design GF= 0.000 Q= 818.96 rpm=4800.",I=  4
  0    818.96002      0.00000      13.00000    
     61.92762
  1    818.96002      0.00000      29.86776    
     61.92762
```

Any suggestions? I don't need a full solution, just a hint to continue. Then I can go on and improve the solution.

EDIT 2: leaving it aside for a minute the fact that I cannot `lapply` my `parse_point`, I tried to concentrate on `parse_point`. Andddd...great! I can now at least parse correctly one data block:

```
library(stringr) 
index = 1
split_text_line = strsplit(s[index],split=" +")[[1]]
Point = str_sub(split_text_line[4],4)
GFin = as.numeric(split_text_line[6])
Qin =  as.numeric(split_text_line[8])
rpm = as.numeric(str_extract(split_text_line[9],"[:digit:]+"))
index = index + 1
split_text_line = strsplit(s[index],split=" +")[[1]]
q1 = split_text_line[3]
GF1 = split_text_line[4]
pe1 = split_text_line[5]
index = index + 1
eff1 = as.numeric(str_trim(s[index]))
index = index + 1
split_text_line = strsplit(s[index],split=" +")[[1]]
q2 = split_text_line[3]
GF2 = split_text_line[4]
pe2 = split_text_line[5]
index = index + 1
eff2 = as.numeric(str_trim(s[index]))
df = data.frame(Point=Point, GFin=GFin, Qin=Qin, rpm=rpm, q1=q1, q2=q2,
                GF1=GF1, GF2=GF2, pe1=pe1, pe2=pe2, eff1=eff1, eff2=eff2)
```

where `s` is the character vector generated by the script above. However, I still have the issue of applying this parsing algorithm to all data blocks. I could do it with a `for` loop, but isn't there any faster way?

Comment: Start with `readLines` and let us know when you get stuck. Show your code (start with just the first 10 or 14 lines), and we can help you with specific problems.

Comment: You are going to need to write a function which reads 5 lines from the file, extracts the values, then `rbind` them all together to form a `data.frame`. Frankly, I'd go raw input -> CSV, then use read.csv. Do the two steps in separate scripts

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions, tomorrow I'll try to implement them and get back to you

Comment: @kdopen, just for my understanding: are you suggesting reading all the file and then rewriting it as CSV (comma separated values), then using read.csv, or are you suggesting to read 5 lines (one data block) at a time and parse it?

Comment: @DeltaIV Both. Given that the file is likely huge, you don't want to read the whole thing into memory. Instead, create a file, write out the column headers, then read the input file 5 lines at a time. For each five lines read, create and output one line for the new CSV file. My thoughts are that you will want to clean/tidy the data once (in the first script), but read it many times for analysis (in the second script). No point converting it for every run of the analysis script.

Comment: @kdopen, hmmm, you raise a good point, I didn't think of it. But now I've invested too much time on the "convert & read" solution. I want to at least complete it and see how much computational time it requires. Can you help me completing my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think a little bit sideways here. You have a list of text lines, which you want to process 5 at a time. So, pass `lapply` a list of indices into the list of data

```
lapply(seq(1,length(s), 5), function (x) { parse_point(s[x:x+4]) })
```

This will call `parse_point` with each group of 5 lines in the source file.

You could also modify `parse_point` to take the array index `x` instead of a list of lines. Then it's just

```
lapply(seq(1,length(s), 5), parse_point)
```

You may need to either `unlist` the result of the `lapply` or consider using `sapply` instead.

Comment: parentheses are needed around `x+4`, i.e., you need to correct t `parse_point(s[x:x+4])` to `parse_point(s[x:(x+4)])`, or R misinterprets the indices.

Comment: I implemented your first solution, as  `data_list = lapply(seq(1,length(s),nlines), function (x) { parse_point(s[x:(x+nlines-1)]) })` followed by`data=do.call("rbind",data_list)` . Strangely, the execution time, as measured from `proc.time`, is more or less the same than with the `for` loop . Thus, I'd like to try the second one. However, I don't understand how I should modify `parse.point`. How do I pass `x` to `parse_point`? In your second call, `parse.point` doesn't have arguments. Can you explain?

Comment: ps I measured the execution time on my real file, which is way bigger. Of course the sample input provided here is too short for benchmarking, unless `replicate` is used, or a larger sample file is creating by copying multiple times the existing lines.